# Upload local file to FTP server using PHP

Tags: php, ftp

I have searched everywhere but didn't got a perfect answer.
I am using WAMP to run PHP on local machine. I have an  tag to accept file from local machine and have to upload this to FTP server.

My code is working perfectly fine but only if file is present directly on base path i.e. /wamp/www/ but if I pick file from desktop to upload, it didn't actually pass path of file to action php file instead just pass on file name.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality?

Thanks
Saransh

Comment: Idk. Maybe it's a sandbox for safety reasons. Or it's something about the paths. You also could "upload" it to a xampp directory first and delete it after upload to server has finished. How does your script work? You select a file like a http-upload?